# How to design a procedure with unique implementations for different hardware features?

Tags: c++, optimization

Let's say that I have a function or procedure which I'd like to execute differently depending on a machine's hardware feature set.  If feature A is present, a specific block of code which exploits feature A is executed.  If not, and feature B is present, then code exploiting feature B is executed.  And so on through N features.  Pseudo-code would look like the following:

```
function doStuff()
    if (featureA)
        /* Use feature A to do stuff. */
    else if (featureB)
        /* Use feature B to do stuff. */
    else if...
    ...
    else
        /* Do stuff generically. */
```

Clearly, the extended `if-else` can get messy.  Furthermore, if this were a performance-critical section of code, it would be nice to avoid repeated conditional checks.

I know of some designs for code that targets multiple platforms, such as splitting up platform-specific implementations into platform-specific versions of the same class or file.  Or, for smaller sections of code (in C/C++), `#ifdef`s could separate platform code.  However, this is a case where the platform is the same, but the hardware might differ; for example, different models of an Intel CPU.

So, is there a better way to code something like this?  How might the function, or code and structures surrounding the function, be designed?  Prefer answers that could be applied in C++.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: I'm most interested in something that could be applied in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a language with objects, I'd simply create subclasses for each hardware configuration, and instantiate one based on the available hardware.

If you are using C, and are worried about performance, I'd create several functions with identical signatures, then use a function pointer to pick the one for the available hardware.

For example:

```
/* global function pointer for doing stuff */
void (*doStuff)(int) = NULL;

/* various available implementations */
void doStuffFeatureA(int n) { ... }
void doStuffFeatureB(int n) { ... }
void doStuffGeneric(int n) { ... }

/* this function MUST be called before you try to do stuff */
void initStuff() {
    if (featureA) {
        doStuff = &doStuffFeatureA;
    } else if (featureB) {
        doStuff = &doStuffFeatureB;
    } else {
        doStuff = &doStuffGeneric;
    }
}
```

This way you only need to do the hardware check once; future function calls will simply jump to the address of the correct function. You will need to make sure to initialize the function pointer before you attempt to use it, otherwise your program will crash. And if you are using multiple threads, you need to be extra careful that you don't change the function pointer from more than one thread.

Comment: I believe a common pattern is to set the initial value of the function-pointer to the initialisation function. Thus the first time its called, it sets itself up automatically.

Comment: @Textmode That sounds like an excellent way to earn some extra credit. :-)